# Plotting Location data in R

Tags: r, location, coordinates

Can anyone please tell me how to plot location data in the R language? 
Suppose I have data "Date-time" with X and Y coordinates (latitude and Longitude) as mentioned below;I am trying to do in R language.

```
Date:   2016-02-25 17:21:09.147,    
Location (2.39, 48.71)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want. You can make (1) two graphs, one for X and one for Y or (2) you can generate a plot of X in function of Y or (3) you can make a 3D plot with X, Y and Date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to show just the position using a simple line with time.

Comment: All of the three options I presented could be a simple line, which option where you thinking of? 1-3 or something else?

Comment: I am thinking about the 3rd option.

Comment: In that case, you can try to combine [`plot3d`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) with [`datetick`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html)

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Please update your question to add the essential information (you want a 3D plot) and accept an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To visualise your 3D data, you can use [`plot3d`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) and combine it with [`datetick`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html) to format the time axes.